# Hibernate lookup table with enum

Tags: hibernate, enums, lookup-tables

I am currently trying to learn hibernate and have encountered a problem which looks reasonable from both OOP and DB point of view, and yet I am unable to find solution.

My java part looks more or less like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Vehicles")
class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @Column (name = "UUID")
    UUID id; 
    VehicleType type

    (getters, setters, other values, etc.)
}

enum VehicleType {
    TRUCK,
    TRAILER,
    OTHER;
}
```

and my DB part has two tables - one for vehicles and lookup table for vehicle types:

**Vehicles**

```
UUID VARCHAR (PK)
vehicle_type_id INT (FK to VehicleTypes)
```

**VehicleTypes**

```
vehicle_type_id INT (PK)
vehicle_type VARCHAR
```

My question is, is it possible to arrange this in the presented manner? If it is possible, how to implement it (annotations, etc.). If not, what is the best way to implement similar structure?

**-----EDIT-----**

I have managed to achieve my goal (more or less) using [solution](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeforpersistingaTypesafeEnumerationwithaVARCHARcolumn) described by Anthony Patricio.

DB part stayed the same, while Java part looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Vehicles")
class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @Column (name = "UUID")
    UUID id;
    @Column (name = "vehicle_type_id")
    @Type (type = "VehicleEnumUserType")
    VehicleType type

    (getters, setters, other values, etc.)
}

enum VehicleType {
    TRUCK(1),
    TRAILER(2),
    OTHER(0);

    private int value;
    VehicleType(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static VehicleType fromValue(int value){
        for (VehicleType type : VehicleType.values()){
            if (value == type.value) return type;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value not mapped by VehicleType enum");
    }
}

VehicleEnumUserType implements UserType{
    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.INTEGER};

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] strings, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        int number = resultSet.getInt(strings[0]);
        return resultSet.wasNull() ? null : VehicleType.fromValue(number);
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object o, int i, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (o == null){
            preparedStatement.setNull(i, Types.INTEGER);
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setInt(i, ((VehicleType)o).getValue());
        }
    }
    // other mandatory methods required by UserType interface
}
```

This solution fits my requirements - Vehicle type is restricted both on DB side (by lookup table restriction) and on java side (by VehicleType enum). Moreover, vehicle type is stored as integer, reducing space required to store data. Last but not lest, this solution allows for quite safe addition of new Vehicle Types (e.g. problems related with `EnumType.ORDINAL`).

Hope anyone finds this solution useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "Enumerated" annotation

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
VehicleType type
```

Comment: But I don't have (and i don't want to have) vehicle_type column in the Vehicles table. I only have vehicle_type_id and have no idea how to connect those two pieces of data to form Vehicle object.

Comment: is vehicle_type a string or composite of attributes?

Comment: For now it is just an enum as presented above.

Comment: why do you want it to be vehicle_type_id if its just enumeration?

Comment: I have enums for type control at the Java side. VehicleType table is for velue enforcing at the DB side. I can give the user a read only access to the VehicleType table and ensure that no new vehicle type can be added to the DB.

Comment: that would be a bad design, why not have VechicleType as enum? hibernate maps java model to relational model so if you have enum types then let hibernate map them for you

Comment: I disagree, i think the design is correct to allow for property index on int instead of string if he does need to do a look up on a larger table it will be more performant. You should never let ORM's determine your database structure. Were you able to find a solution for this? I am having a similar issue.

You can use the ordinal Enumerated type, but then anyone using the database has to guess because there is no table to determine.

Comment: @ephemeralCoder i agree ORM should never determine your database structure, ORM is just mapping between Object Orient models and relational models, but this has nothing to do with enumerating it, it is a common case to put a select constraint on fields in database and this is clearly should be mapped to enumeration, and you can always put indexes on string fields also